# GIBCXX_3.4.20 not found error in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'd like to use the Python package (Konlpy) in AWS Lambda. However, the following error occurs:

"Unable to import module 'lambda_function': /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.20' Not found (required by /var/task/_jpype.so)"

How can I fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxFKy.png)

Answer (score 0):

The AWS Lambda is deployed in a clean environment. It does not have the package `Konlpy`, it has no idea what you are trying to import.

In order to achieve this, you can create a [Cloud Formation Stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/deploying-lambda-apps.html). This can bundle up your code and allow you to deploy dependencies for your lambda.